# Replace for loop with std::find_if and a lambda

Tags: c++, boost, stl, c++17

Consider this code:

```cpp
int i{ -1 };
for(i=0; i<size; ++i) if (predicate(i)) break;
bool found{ i < size };
```

This should be simple to replace with std::find_if, but it needs an iterator on integers in the range of 0 to size-1. (The equivalent of C#'s *IEnumerable Enumerable.Range(0, size-1)*.)

Comment: You need C++20 ranges or custom iterators.

Comment: I don't understand how `found` is working here. Won't `i >= 0` be true when the loop exits no matter what?

Comment: Initialization part in `for()` loop happens before condition checked and body executed, so it is not possible that `i` would be negative and it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Then please edit your question to say that. As it stands, the question is confusing to future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with `boost` tag, I assume [`boost::irange`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html) along with [`boost::find_if`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/non_mutating/find_if.html) will do the work:

```cpp
boost::find_if(boost::irange(0, size - 1), predicate);
```